# Getting exact time in ( HH:mm:sss a) format from milliseconds

Tags: android, time

I have to print time in my app in HH:mm:sss AM/PM from milliseconds which is 24 Hours later time .

so to get 24 hours later time to current time i used the code as

```
  public Date roundToNext24Hour() {

    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.setTime(date);
    c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    return c.getTime();
}
```

now i convert this time in HH:mm:sss am/pm format

```
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:sss a");
  timeString = df.format(Utility.roundToNext24Hour())
```

but problem is timestring is always returning time which is 12 hour later not 24 hour later.

please help..

Comment: `c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.setTime(date);` is useless

Comment: What is problem here? After 24 hours you will get same time and that is universal truth. So question is what you are trying to do?

Comment: pankaj wheni am printing time which is coming in timestring it is only after 12 hour later while it must be 24 hour later. like if current time is 04:36 PM then time in timeString is coming 04:00 AM , it should come 04:00 PM

Answer (score 2):

```
Try below code.

Date date = new Date();
          SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a");
          String str = df.format(date);
```